# How do I disable "git requirement" pop up that appears whenever I open RStudio?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, popup, rstudio

A few months ago I was exploring the RStudio settings and enabled version control interface for RStudio projects but because I don't have Xcode or the command line development tools, it's been bugging me with a pop-up every time I open RStudio, "The 'git' command requires the command line development tools," and wants me to install them.

[Popup Window Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfkTS.png)

I know Xcode takes up a lot of storage space and my MacBook has very limited space so I don't want to install them. It's been months now and my tolerance grows thin. I really would like this pop-up to stop. **How do I stop this message from appearing?**

Things I've tried: disabling version control in Git/SVN settings and restart, closing all projects and scripts and restart, reinstalling/updating RStudio and R.

Comment: The popup is confusing, but it is not asking you to install XCode, just Command Line Tools, which is ~130 MB. You can also try just installing git separately

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be related to a call to `/usr/bin/git`, which is the default installed binary for git on a Mac (or at least on mine - MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015), upgraded to Sierra). Executing `/usr/bin/git` (or `/usr/bin/svn`) shows an xcode message, and the dialog.

```
xcode-select: note: no developer tools were found at '/Applications/Xcode.app', requesting install. Choose an option in the dialog to download the command line developer tools.
```

I installed git using Homebrew, so it's now in `/usr/local/bin/git` instead.

My solution was to move `/usr/bin/git` to `/usr/bin/git.bak` (just in case), and symlink to my actual `git` binary with `sudo ln /usr/local/bin/git /usr/bin/git`.

Comment: Doesn’t work for me:
`sudo mv /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/git.bak
mv: rename /usr/bin/git to /usr/bin/git.bak: Operation not permitted

Comment: This might be because the files are not on that path (that path is what was on my Mac, yours might be elsewhere for whatever reason, depending on the OS version etc), or it might be related to System Integrity Protection.

Assuming those file paths & locations are correct, then it will probably be down to SIP being enabled.

Comment: Nope. 
    # ls -l /usr/bin/git
    -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  31456 Jan 23 05:59 /usr/bin/git
I think you're right though - it's SIP.